# exclude ID on avatar

Tags: admin

How to exclude admin on this avatar function ?

```
<div class="single-post-about-author">
    <div class="author-avatar-w"><?php echo get_avatar(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )); ?>
</div>

<div class="author-details">
    <h3 class="author-name"><?php the_author_meta( 'display_name' ); ?></h3>
</div>
```

I am trying to hide admin avatar and display name on my single post

Answer (score 0):

Should help, if user isn't admin show avatar, if user is admin hide avatar.

```
<?php  if(!is_admin()) { ?>

<div class="single-post-about-author">
    <div class="author-avatar-w"><?php echo get_avatar(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )); ?>
</div>

<?php } ?>

<div class="author-details">
    <h3 class="author-name"><?php the_author_meta( 'display_name' ); ?></h3>
</div>
```